# GL_ARB_gpu_shader_fp64 not supported according to glslangValidator.exe, but I actually do?

Tags: glsl, vulkan

I have an AMD Radeon RX 480, and I wrote a fragment shader (GLSL 4.6) that makes use of the GL_ARB_gpu_shader_fp64 extension;

According to the [Database](https://opengl.gpuinfo.org/), my GPU should support the GL_ARB_gpu_shader_fp64 extension, but when I compile the shader with the **glslangValidator.exe**, I get:

*'#extension' : extension not supported: GL_ARB_gpu_shader_fp64*

Same thing happens to my other pc, that has an Intel Graphics HD 620 (That supports that extension, too).

Can someone explain me what's happening?

Comment: "*I wrote a fragment shader (GLSL 4.6) that makes use of the GL_ARB_gpu_shader_fp64 extension*" No, you did not. If you wrote a shader under GLSL 4.60, you already have that functionality. So there's no reason to enable an extension for something you can already do.

Comment: Oh good, so I can actually remove that line from the shader code. Problem is, it does with other extensions too. For example my AMD Radeon RX 480 supports GL_AMD_gpu_shader_int64, but when compiling the shader it says '#extension' : extension not supported: GL_AMD_gpu_shader_int64.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're doing. From your tags, you appear to be writing GLSL code meant for consumption by Vulkan. But you seem to be basing what is "supported" off of what *OpenGL* provides, as if OpenGL and Vulkan were the same API and you're expecting a shader built for one API to compile into a different one.

Comment: I thought these GLSL extension worked for both API, so I guess I was wrong. By the way, I just found out also GL_ARB_gpu_shader_int64 is already supported without including it in GLSL 4.50+, so I don't understand why my compiler doesn't recognize uint64_t types.

Comment: "*I just found out also GL_ARB_gpu_shader_int64 is already supported without including it in GLSL 4.50+*" No, it isn't. Look at the GLSL 4.60 specification; there is no `int64` type at all. There are `double` types, but no other 64-bit types.

Comment: But in https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_gpu_shader_int64.txt you can find "This extension is written against version 4.50 of the OpenGL Shading Language Specification." Doesn't this mean it should be present in GLSL 4.50+?

Comment: [No, it does not.](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Extension#How_to_read)

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When compiling GLSL using glslang into SPIR-V of any form, the available set of extensions does not care about the nature of the platform you are compiling on. After all, the whole point of an intermediate language is to be able to pre-compile your shader on one platform, then ship it in compiled form to the place where the user will execute it. That is when any extensions will be checked against the available set of extensions for that platform.

So basically, glslang assumes any extensions which could be valid for the target language are valid.

However, when compiling GLSL into SPIR-V for Vulkan consumption, the set of extensions that glslang is aware of are those extensions which are appropriate for Vulkan consumption. These extensions can be found in [this GLSL Github repo](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/GLSL). This set of extensions is specific to Vulkan.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time, this is what I was looking for.